# Run SSIS Package which developed in VS 2015 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2015, service, ssis, integration, bids

I have developed an SSIS Package with VS 2015 Professional and try to start this outside of the Project.

When I try to execute the Package I see this error message:

[image: This picture will show you the error message]

After this I asked the Infrastructure guys at work and they said me that I need the Integration Service 2016 to execute this package and that they do not have this.

What do I need to do to execute this package?

Comment: You need SQL Server installed which comes with SSIS

Comment: I now, but which Version, when I have developed the package with VS 2015.

Comment: In SSDT in VS 2015, if you have made no changes to your project it would be targetted at SQL Server 2016. However in the project properties you can change the target server version to an earlier version of SQL Server if you need to.